# How to load an XML "Unattend answer file" into the current Windows 10 installation?

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, kiosk

There are a few possible customization for Windows 10 Enterprise, such as [Custom Logon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/enterprise/custom-logon).

This page explains indeed how to create such a file using DISM for a *future* Windows installation image, but how to simply apply such XML files to an already installed Windows 10 Pro or Enterprise system?

Let's assume this file is saved into `myconfig.xml`:

```
<settings pass="specialize">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Embedded-EmbeddedLogon" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <BrandingNeutral>17</BrandingNeutral>
      <AnimationDisabled>1</AnimationDisabled>
      <NoLockScreen>1</NoLockScreen>
      <UIVerbosityLevel>1</UIVerbosityLevel>
      <HideAutoLogonUI>1</HideAutoLogonUI>
    </component>
</settings>
```

**How to load it?**

Is there a:

```
bcdedit ... --file=myconfig.xml
```

or another way?

Note: I have already done:  "Turn Windows Features On and Off" > Device Lockdown > Custom logon.

Comment: You might get a better answer on serverfault or stackoverflow as this is more a business-need & [superuser usually focuses on home users](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)